# Customizing EF F# Query Translator

Tags: entity-framework, linq, f#

In an answer to [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806981/asynchronous-ef-query-in-f) I was told to use `QueryExtensions` to achieve async computations with F# and Entity Framework, and I'm using that advice successfully.

For example, I have the following function:

```
let headAsync query =
    query
    |> QueryableExtensions.FirstAsync
    |> Async.AwaitTask
```

that can be used this way:

```
async {
    let! entity =
        query {
            for e in context.MyEntities do
            sortBy e.Id
        } |> headAsync
    return entity
}
```

It'd be nice though to use my new function as a query expression. I've written this:

```
type QueryBuilderEx() =
    inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()

    [<CustomOperation("headAsync")>]
    member __.HeadAsync<'T, 'Q when 'Q :> System.Linq.IQueryable<'T>> (source: Linq.QuerySource<'T, 'Q>) : Async<'T> =
        let queryable = source.Source :?> 'Q
        queryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

let query2 = QueryBuilderEx()
```

And trying to use it like this:

```
async {
    let! entity =
        query2 {
            for e in context.MyEntities do
            sortBy e.Id
            headAsync
        }
    return entity
}
```

This code compiles fine, but throws the following exception at runtime:

> System.NotSupportedException: This is not a valid query expression. The method 'Microsoft.FSharp.Control.FSharpAsync`1[Entities.MyEntity] HeadAsync[MyEntity,IQueryable`1](Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuerySource`2[Entities.MyEntity,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Entities.MyEntity]])' was used in a query but is not recognized by the F#-to-LINQ query translator. Check the specification of permitted queries and consider moving some of the operations out of the query expression

So, is the extension of the standard LINQ translator possible, or I should stick to my previous `headAsync` implementation in form of ordinary function without messing with `QueryBuilder`?

Comment: You can try to replace HeadAsync with its body (example can be found here http://www.fssnip.net/go). However I doubt that linq-to-sql query translator is able to translate FirstOrDefaultAsync as well. Most likely the only way to support that will be reimplementing translator with recent EF contracts.

Comment: @ntr, thank you, that's really interesting. I would accept this as an answer after I try it in my project.